# Silly Limit with Exponetiation

Tags: limits

I found, using exponetiation and l'hopital, that:

$\lim \limits_{x\to 0} x^{\sqrt x} = \infty$

However, the limit is 1 using matlab. How can I find such limit?

Thanks

Comment: How did you use L'Hôpital here?

Comment: Take the logarithm, $\sqrt{x}\cdot\log x \to 0$ for $x \to 0^+$. So exponentiating again, we get $1$ for the limit.

Answer (score 4):

Rewrite as $(\sqrt{x}^{\sqrt{x}})(\sqrt{x}^{\sqrt{x}})$ and quote the  presumably familiar result that $\lim_{y\to 0^+}y^y=1$. So the answer is $(1)(1)$.

Note that the question should really ask for
$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0^+} x^{\sqrt{x}}$.

Comment: One might also use $ \ \lim_{x \rightarrow 0^{+}} (x^{x^{(1/2)}}) = \lim_{x \rightarrow 0^{+}} (x^{x/2}) = (\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^{+}} x^x)^{(1/2)} , \ $ since $ \ \lim_{x \rightarrow 0^{+}} x^x \ $ might be a more familiar result (that is, one the instructor or the book did, or that the student has already been asked to establish)...

Comment: I **was** referring to the $x^x$, in the guise $t^t$ where $t=\sqrt{x}$.

Comment: All right, I was just wondering whether OP would understand the slight subtlety there...

Comment: Thank you for your comment, it helped me add a sentence to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the substitution $\sqrt{x}=t$ and compute
$$
\lim_{t\to0^+}(t^2)^t=\lim_{t\to0^+}t^{2t}=
\lim_{t\to0^+}\exp(2t\log t)
$$
Since $\lim_{t\to0^+}t\log t=0$ (it's a standard exercise), you can conclude that your limit is $\exp(0)=1$.